# drop menu not showing up once I added a different name to div

Tags: html, css, navigation, dropdown

I have 3 drop menus and all were working fine until I needed to change the width of one and added a 3 to the name to make it a different class. Now the list does not show. Can someone tell me what I am missing? I have removed the alternate class name and added it back one at a time to see if I can find the issue but I am not able to.

My first snippet shows how the first two lists are suppose to work and how the third one is stuck. I have already tried it with the commas in between but it does not work at all if I put the comma in between the first two, the first two lists display if I only put a comma between the second two tags; however I cannot get the third list to hide.

This little snag just came about as I am trying to finish up a project. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

```css
#nav {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin-top: -10px;
 margin-left: -40px;
 background: #000; 
 padding: 20px;
 height: 1px;
 width: 510px;
 }

#nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Hind Siliguri', sans-serif;
  background: #898;
  border: solid #049 5px;
  padding: 8px;
  margin: 5px;
  }

#nav a:hover {
  transition: background-color .5s ease;
  background-color: #ded;
  color: #000;
  border-radius: 15px; 
}

#nav li:hover {
 transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1.125);
}

nav li {
  transform: rotate(5deg);
  float: left;
}

.drop {
  display: inline;
  text-align: left;
}

li a, .drop{
  display: inline-block;
}

li.list {
  display: inline-block;
}

.drop-list, .drop-list3 {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 6px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 0px;
  min-width: 95px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.drop-list3 {
  min-width: 105px;
}

.drop-list a, .drop-list3 a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  padding: 3px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: left;
}

.drop-list a:hover, .drop-list3 a:hover {
  background-color: #ded;
  color: #000;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.list:hover .drop-list, .drop-list3 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul id="nav">
    <li class="list"><a href="#" class="drop">Menu one</a>
      <div class="drop-list">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
    </li>
    <li class="list"><a href="#" class="drop">Menu two</a>
        <div class="drop-list">
      <a href="#">Link A</a>
      <a href="#">Link B</a>
      <a href="#">Link C</a>
    </div>
      </li>
    <li class="list"><a href="#">Menu three</a>
      <div class="drop-list3">
      <a href="#">Link Uno</a>
      <a href="#">Link Dos</a>
      <a href="#">Link Tres</a>
    </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

```css
#nav {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin-top: -10px;
 margin-left: -40px;
 background: #000; 
 padding: 20px;
 height: 1px;
 width: 510px;
 }

#nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Hind Siliguri', sans-serif;
  background: #898;
  border: solid #049 5px;
  padding: 8px;
  margin: 5px;
  }

#nav a:hover {
  transition: background-color .5s ease;
  background-color: #ded;
  color: #000;
  border-radius: 15px; 
}

#nav li:hover {
 transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1.125);
}

nav li {
  transform: rotate(5deg);
  float: left;
}

.drop {
  display: inline;
  text-align: left;
}

li a, .drop{
  display: inline-block;
}

li.list {
  display: inline-block;
}

.drop-list, .drop-list3 {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 6px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 0px;
  min-width: 95px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.drop-list3 {
  min-width: 105px;
}

.drop-list a, .drop-list3 a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  padding: 3px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: left;
}

.drop-list a:hover, .drop-list3 a:hover {
  background-color: #ded;
  color: #000;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.list:hover .drop-list .drop-list3 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul id="nav">
    <li class="list"><a href="#" class="drop">Menu one</a>
      <div class="drop-list">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
    </li>
    <li class="list"><a href="#" class="drop">Menu two</a>
        <div class="drop-list">
      <a href="#">Link A</a>
      <a href="#">Link B</a>
      <a href="#">Link C</a>
    </div>
      </li>
    <li class="list"><a href="#">Menu three</a>
      <div class="drop-list3">
      <a href="#">Link Uno</a>
      <a href="#">Link Dos</a>
      <a href="#">Link Tres</a>
    </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to mention .list one time extra -- your selectors:

```
.list:hover .drop-list, 
.drop-list3 
{
  display: block;
}
```

what it needs to be:

```
.list:hover .drop-list, 
.list:hover .drop-list3 
{
  display: block;
}
```

otherwise your telling .drop-list3 to display block by default, not on hover.

you could just apply the one class "drop-list" - you don't need .drop-list3 class, as in:

```
<nav>
  <ul id="nav">
    <li class="list"><a href="#" class="drop">Menu one</a>
      <div class="drop-list">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
    </li>
    <li class="list"><a href="#" class="drop">Menu two</a>
        <div class="drop-list">
      <a href="#">Link A</a>
      <a href="#">Link B</a>
      <a href="#">Link C</a>
    </div>
      </li>
    <li class="list"><a href="#">Menu three</a>
      <div class="drop-list"> <!-- not "drop-list3" -->
      <a href="#">Link Uno</a>
      <a href="#">Link Dos</a>
      <a href="#">Link Tres</a>
    </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

css shorter:

```
.list:hover .drop-list
{
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Carol! You rock! That worked like magic! I changed the name of the div for that list because I needed to change the min-width for that list only. But you answer helped me :-)